# How to use same layout with different text and images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` to show a list of countries at the moment if you click on a country it opens that country's activity and shows the title, video and flag

Instead of making 200+ activities and put the title, video and flag in each. Is it possible to use one activity with all the titles, videos and images and make switch statements or something so that it switches between all them using the same layout file.

So if the user clicks on the countries it opens the same activity everytime but just switches and bring up the correct title, video and image for that country.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initControls();
}

private void initControls() {

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Countries");

    }

    final String[] versions = {

            "Afghanistan",
            "Albania",

            .....
    };


    ArrayList<Properties> countries = new ArrayList<Properties>();

    for (String version : versions) {
        Properties feed = new Properties();

        feed.setTitle(version);
        countries.add(feed);
    }

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(countries);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class CardViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static ArrayList<Properties> dataSet;

public CardViewDataAdapter(ArrayList<Properties> countries) {

    dataSet = countries;
}


@Override
public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.card_view, null);

    return new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    Properties fp = dataSet.get(i);

    viewHolder.countryName.setText(fp.getTitle());
    viewHolder.feed = fp;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView countryName;

    public Properties feed;
    private final Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        context = itemView.getContext();

        countryName = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.cName);

        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Intent intent;
                switch (getAdapterPosition()){
                    case 0:
                        intent =  new Intent(context, Afghanistan.class);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        intent =  new Intent(context, Albania.class);
                        break;


                    .......

                }
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

}
}
```

Country Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/countryVideo"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/countryFlag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Afganistan

```
public class Afganistan extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.country_activity);

    TextView countryTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countryTitle);
    countryTitle.setText("Afganistan");

    VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.countryVideo);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.afganistanVideo;
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    view.start();
    view.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });

    ImageView countryFlag = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.countryFlag);
    countryFlag.setImageResource(R.drawable.afganistanFlag);
}
}
```

Comment: create a single activity and pass all the data you need to print in views using intents.

Comment: create a single activity `&` in `onclick()` method of recyclerview - pass all the data you need to print in views using intents.

Comment: make a arraylist of  parcelable class for your all data and send object  of parcelable  corresponding to position of row of recyclerview. get object in your next activity using intent and set data using that object

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing the data in the intent, as extras.
Replace the code inside the onClick() method with the code below,

```
        Intent countryIntent = new Intent(context, CountryActivity.class);
        countryIntent.putExtra("title", versions[getAdapterPosition()]);
        countryIntent.putExtra("url", /*set the url as specified above*/]);
        context.startActivity(countryIntent);
```

and use below code inside the onCreate() method of Afganistan Activity

```
        Intent countryIntent = getIntent();
        countryTitle.setText(countryIntent.getStringExtra("title"));
        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + countryIntent
                .getStringExtra("url");
```

Comment: This is so clear @Moses have been struggling with this problem for a while, can you refer me to more content on this technique please

Comment: @samuelowino the below link as all the api methods of intent. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html